# Configure two SSL sites in IIS7 with the same IP and port

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, https, web

I would like to know how could I configure two sites for use as `https`. The sites are placed in the same machine (and the same IP). And I would like to use on both the default port 443.

For example:

[image]

I want an application inside `site1.com` to be SSL, and other application inside `site2.com` to be SSL too. Is this possible, and how could I configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have 2 different IP addresses on the server for this to work. You will have the first site bound to the first IP and the second site to the second. In the bindings of the website you have to explicitly choose the correct IP address. Then you can select the SSL certificate for each site.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't going to go with Wildcard SSL Certificate, your only hope is [Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). yet, SNI is only supported in IIS **version 8**.

See http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability